# Get 5 items from feed and save as new file

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed

How can I get the first 5 items from a feed that has more than 10 items, and save as a new XML file?

I was using something like this to get all the feed data, but some feeds have more items than necessary.

```php
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/rss');
file_put_contents('newfile.xml', $xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-parser:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/rss');
```

This gives you a [SimpleXML-object](http://se.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which you can iterate the feed with a `for`-loop for example. The exact syntax depends on the feed you want to fetch, you should post the feed structure if you want more help :)